# How to save response from the sso login into async-storage ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a screen in React Native named as Login. The Login screen is being fetched from webview. The architecture of application is :

1. Application need to have native splash screen.
2. It should open the login screen in webview.
3. When a succesful login is done from the webview then the application need to save the token that is being fetched into the asyncstorage.
4. If token is saved then application needs to be redirect to Dashboard screen.

How can i achieve this?
I have rendered the WebView URL successfully but and injected few Javascript also. But i am unable to save the token into async-storage. Have any one done it anywhere?

This is how my source code looks like

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Alert, UIManager, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import WebView, { WebViewNavigation } from 'react-native-webview';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);


const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<any>();
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [logMessages, setLogMessages] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const [shouldRedirect, setShouldRedirect] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const webViewRef = useRef<WebView>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Log messages =>", logMessages)
  }, [logMessages]);

  const handleWebViewMessage = (event: any) => {
    // Parse the message received from the WebView
    const data = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
    console.log("Webview Data =>", data)
    setLogMessages((prev) => [...prev, data]);
  };


  const saveTokenToAsyncStorage = async (data: any) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log("Data saved to async storage")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Errror saviung the data to async storage =>", error)
    }
  }

  const handleShouldLoadWithRequest = (event: any) => {
    if (event.title === "Portal") {
      webViewRef.current?.stopLoading()
      navigation.replace("Dashboard")
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }


  const handleNavigationStateChange = (navState: WebViewNavigation) => {
    if (navState.title === "Portal") {
      navigation.replace("Dashboard",)
      webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(`
        function (){
          var style = document.createElement('style');
          style.innerHTML = 'body { display: none !important;}';
          document.head.appendChild(style);
        } ()
      `)
      webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(`
        const data ={
          hasLoggedInOnce: true,
          accessToken : 'TOKEN',
          accessTokenExpirationDate: 'EXPIRATION_DATE',
          refreshToken: 'REFRESH_TOKEN'
        };
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data));
      `)
    } else if (navState.title === "https://mbl-intranetsso.server247.info/Account/Login") {
      console.log("Login page")
      webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(`
        document.getElementByClassName('btn btn-danger form-btn btn-primary').addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log("Button clicked")        
        })
      `)
    }

  }

  const webViewScript = `
    (function(){
      var originalConsolelog = console.log;
      console.log = function(){
        var logMessage = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(logMessage);
        originalConsolelog.apply(console, arguments);
      }
    })();
  `

  return (
    <>
      <WebView
        injectedJavaScript={webViewScript}
        ref={webViewRef}
        source={{ uri: 'https://mbl-intranetsso.server247.info/Account/Login' }}
        onError={(syntheticEvent) => {
          const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
          console.warn('WebView error: ', nativeEvent);
        }}
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
        bounces={false}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        onNavigationStateChange={handleNavigationStateChange}
        onMessage={handleWebViewMessage}
        onLoadStart={() => setVisible(true)}
        onLoadEnd={() => setVisible(false)}
        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={handleShouldLoadWithRequest}
      />
      {visible && (
        <ActivityIndicator
          style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}
          size="large"
          color="#0000ff"
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

This is my config file for sso login that has been provided to me for logging in. I dont know how to use it.

```
export const __RUNTIME_CONFIG__ = {
    "REACT_APP_BASE_URL": "https://mbl-intranet.server247.info/",
    "REACT_APP_SELF_UPDATE_URL": "https://mbl-intranet.server247.info/selfupdate/api",
    "REACT_APP_AUTHORITY": "https://mbl-intranetsso.server247.info",
    "REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URL": "http://localhost:3000",
    "REACT_APP_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL": "https://mbl-intranet.server247.info/",
};


import { __RUNTIME_CONFIG__ } from "./config";

export const oidcSettings = {
    authority: __RUNTIME_CONFIG__.REACT_APP_AUTHORITY,
    client_id: "Intranet_App",
    redirect_uri: __RUNTIME_CONFIG__.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URL,
    scope: "address email offline_access openid phone Portal profile role",
    response_type: "code",
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    post_logout_redirect_uri:
        __RUNTIME_CONFIG__.REACT_APP_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL,
    dummyClientSecret: "",
    showDebugInformation: true,
    oidc: true,
    requireHttps: false,
    autoLogin: true,
};
```